# Python "A PWM object already exists for this GPIO channel"

Tags: python, runtime-error

```
#import required libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Configure GPIO setting
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

#constants for motor control
PWMA = 36
PWMB = 33
AIN1 = 40
AIN2 = 38
BIN1 = 37
BIN2 = 35

#Speed set to
speed_input = int(25)
speed = speed_input

left_speed = None
right_speed = None

def drive_init():
    global left_speed, right_speed

    print("Initializing the GPIO ports supporting drive ops.")
    #GPIOsettings
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    #MC directions as output
    GPIO.setup(AIN1, GPIO.OUT, initial = False)
    GPIO.setup(AIN2, GPIO.OUT, initial = False)
    GPIO.setup(BIN1, GPIO.OUT, initial = False)
    GPIO.setup(BIN2, GPIO.OUT, initial = False)

    #Set motors to off first
    GPIO.output(AIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(AIN2, False)
    GPIO.output(BIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(BIN2, False)

    #set pins as out
    GPIO.setup(PWMA, GPIO.OUT, initial = True)
    GPIO.setup(PWMB, GPIO.OUT, initial = True)

    left_speed = GPIO.PWM(PWMA, 50)
    right_speed = GPIO.PWM(PWMB, 50)
    left_speed.start(0)
    right_speed.start(0)

    #Enable MC with high on enable
    GPIO.output(PWMA, True)
    GPIO.output(PWMB, True)
```

When attempting to run an action in my program, for instance:

```
def forward(speed, sec):
    print(f"Moving forward for at {speed}")
    GPIO.output(AIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(AIN2, True)
    GPIO.output(BIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(BIN2, True)
    left_speed.ChangeDutyCycle(speed)
    right_speed.ChangeDutyCycle(speed)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(AIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(AIN2, False)
    GPIO.output(BIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(BIN2, False)
```

the program works as intended for the first input, but upon entering in another input, it returns the error "A PWM object already exists for this GPIO channel" referencing the lines " left_speed = GPIO.PWM(PWMA, 50)" and "GPIO.setup(BIN2, GPIO.OUT, initial = False)". Im still pretty new to coding and not 100% sure what the issue actually is. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're calling `drive_init()` on each action, rather than once at the start of your program.

Comment: That did it! had my driv_init in a bad spot, thank you very much